# Tool for cleaning up CSS colours

Tags: css

Can anyone recommend a tool to help clean up the colours used in a CSS file?

We have a CSS file with 196 different colours defined in it. Most of the colours are only slight variation of each other. We would like to be able to select multiple similar colours and re-map them to a single colour.

TopStyle allows you to see the colour palette of your CSS and replace them individually,  but won't allow you to select multiple colours to replace in one go.

Are there any useful tools out there that might help us?

Comment: Does Find/Replace in a text editor answer to your question ?

Comment: Although I have no personal need for it, this makes me want to write a tool to do this. I could see it being useful.

Comment: Find and replace is the solution we were forced to use in the end, although it was time consuming and frustrating. A tool to allow you to select a number of colours and batch replace them with a single replacement colour would have been very useful, and I am sure would be useful in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I would do a PHP parser to find the values of the colors (some regular expression to match #;) and then a replace... I dont know of any tool that would do this.

Comment: I think the problem there is that you would need to do a visual mapping of the colours found by the parser. I am sure you could write something in almost any language to do this, but it would take time to develop.

Comment: you could do an arithmetic comparison on the hex values of the colours and group them accordingly